# Simple Hello World servlet giving error 404 in Eclipse Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I am trying to follow a very simple Hello World servlet tutorial from [this link](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/3/Tomcat-Hello-World-Servlet-using-Eclipse-IDE). I have followed all steps as written, but when I run it on the tomcat7 server (downloaded from within eclipse), it gives me an HTTP error 404, saying that the requested source is not available.

Note that my server is working fine on

> localhost:8080

. But the servlet -

> localhost:8080/HelloWorldServlet/HelloWorld

is giving me this error.

Comment: Can you access tomcat manager ? can you screen shot ?

Comment: What is shown in the Console view when you launch Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

It means Tomcat cannot map your url to existing servlet method. Are you sure, you covered all steps correctly? Hard to say with no details included.

Comment: All steps, including the code, are followed line by line. What details can I add ?

Comment: You may double check if context root is set correctly on "HelloWorldServlet" and created servlet has "/HelloWorld" mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the application name after the url, if you upload it to gitHub maybe I can provide more info.

Comment: try to access  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/HelloWorldServlet/HelloWorld (provided your port is 8080)

Comment: Doesn't work. I have searched everywhere online, there seems to be no solution.